# Query for two most recent order dates in separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to the example shown below.

```
AccountNo  DateOfOrder    OrderID   
-----------------------------------------   
 123       March 1 2010   1   
 222       March 3 2010   2   
 123       April 1 2010   3   
 345       March 15 2010  77   
 123       june 1 2010    55   
 123       march 5 2010   33   
 345       march 1 2010   99   
 222       june 1 2010    7   
 222       june 2 2010    22
```

I need a query that outputs   three columns:

`AccountNo`, `MostRecentDateOfOrder`, `SecondMostRecentDateOfOrder`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Supported sql functions and operators vary a lot by db vendor and version. Be sure to include your db version in the question tags to get the most appropriate answer for your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify which version of SQL Server but you can use CTE and a `PIVOT` for this in SQL Server 2005+:

```
;with cte as
(
  select accountno, dateoforder, orderid,
    row_number() over(partition by accountno 
                      order by dateoforder desc) rn
  from yourtable
)
select accountno,
  [1] MostRecentOrder,
  [2] SecondMostRecent
from 
(
  select accountno, dateoforder, rn
  from cte
) x
pivot 
(
  max(dateoforder)
  for rn in ([1], [2])
) p
```

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec095/4)

Comment: You should add that this works for SQL Server 2005+

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it in Oracle:-

```
SELECT MAX(ACCOUNTNO), 
       MAX(DateOfOrder) AS SecondMostRecentDateOfOder,
       MIN(DateOfOrder) AS MostRecentDateOfOrder 
FROM (
SELECT ACCOUNTNO, DateOfOrder, RANK() OVER (order by ACCOUNTNO, DateOfOrderdesc) RANK
FROM TABLE
)
WHERE RANK < 3;
```